# Vanilla JS: How do I return dynamic html so I can reuse it in element.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

***What I'm building:***
Hi guys, I'm trying to build a memory game and in order to do it, I have to shuffle the deck and reinsert the cards into the HTML.

***Problem:***
I'm having trouble with reinserting the shuffled deck's HTML into the DOM, because it appears to be returning the value "null".

***My attempt at solving this***

I've created the function createHTML which is meant to compile all the html generated by generateCardHTML, and return html. However, 'return deck' doesn't seem to do anything, although console.log(deck) returns the html exactly as I expected.

```
cards = ['card1', 'card1',
'card2','card2',
'card3','card3',
];


function initGame() {
    const shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);

    // generates each li
    function generateCardHTML(card) {
      return `<li class="card"><i class="${card}"></i></li>`
    };

    // PROBLEM BEGINS HERE

    function createHTML(){
      let deck = "";
      shuffledCards.forEach(function(card) {
        const genHTML = generateCardHTML(card);
        deck += genHTML;
      })
      return deck;
    };
  createHTML();
};

initGame();

const gameDeck = document.querySelector('.card');

gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

The closest thing I found to my problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845296/return-html-code-in-javascript) but it doesn't seem to address the same issue. Either that or I'm just too inexperienced to understand it.

Comment: off topic: you can simplify the content of `initGame()` down to `return shuffle(cards).map(generateCardHTML).join("");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the return value of `initGame()` to `gameDeck.innerHTML`, while `initGame()` does not return anything. You probably want

```js
cards = ['card1', 'card1',
'card2','card2',
'card3','card3',
];


function initGame() {
    const shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);

    // generates each li
    function generateCardHTML(card) {
      return '<li class="card"><i class="${card}">'+card+'</i></li>'
    };

    // PROBLEM BEGINS HERE

    function createHTML(){
      let deck = "";
      shuffledCards.forEach(function(card) {
        const genHTML = generateCardHTML(card);
        deck += genHTML;
      })
      return deck;
    };
  return createHTML();
};

initGame();

const gameDeck = document.querySelector('.card');

gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();



// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

```html
<ol class="card">
</ol>
```

**Edit :** Make sure your `gameDeck` element is loaded when the script run.

Comment: I tried that, didn't seem to work though. The only thing you changed was adding return createHTML() right?

Comment: Yes. What do you get now? Does console.log(initGame()) print the HTML you want?

Comment: I included a code snippet which works well. Did you run the script before or after your HTML elements are actually loaded?

Comment: This code seems to be what you're looking for, can you explain what is it thats not working @Sanjay.

Answer (score 1):

Because initGame() is not returning a value, you have to return a value which is the returned value of `createHTML()` in this scenario.

like this

```js
cards = ['card1', 'card1',
  'card2', 'card2',
  'card3', 'card3',
];


function initGame() {
  const shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);

  // generates each li
  function generateCardHTML(card) {
    return `<li class="card"><i class="${card}"></i> ${card}</li>`
  };

  function createHTML() {
    let deck = "";
    shuffledCards.forEach(function(card) {
      const genHTML = generateCardHTML(card);
      deck += genHTML;
    })
    
    return deck;
  };
   
  // NEED TO RETURN SOMETHING
  return createHTML();
};

// THERE IS NO NEED FOR THIS
// initGame();

const gameDeck = document.querySelector('.card');

gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

```html
<ul class='card'></ul>
```

I also added the `card` value into the `li` as text so you can see it, try to run the code and you will get the correct output

Comment: forEach works perfectly fine. It is only missing a return.

Comment: yeahhhh my bad!

Comment: @sphinxplayer where should return go?

Comment: @Sanjay Look at the other answer. Dont forget to remove your first call to initGame().

Comment: I updated the answer with correct information to avoid confusion to other people who experience the same issue :)